# Haskell sum a list of integers

Tags: list, haskell

lately I've been trying to learn Haskell and now I'm stuck at the following problem:

```hs
-- sumList

sumList :: List -> Integer

sumList l = sum l
```

Now I get the following error message in VS Code:

```
{
    "resource": "/home/santino/Studium_Informatik/Studium_Informatik/UnitTest/unittest.hs",
    "owner": "Haskell0",
    "code": "-Wdeferred-type-errors",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "• Couldn't match type ‘List’ with ‘t0 Integer’\n  Expected type: List -> Integer\n    Actual type: t0 Integer -> Integer\n• In the expression: sum\n  In an equation for ‘sumList’: sumList = sum",
    "source": "typecheck",
    "startLineNumber": 22,
    "startColumn": 11,
    "endLineNumber": 22,
    "endColumn": 14
}
```

I have tried googeling the question, but I only get results from Integer to Integer and not from List to Integer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```hs
sumList :: [Integer] -> Integer
sumList l = sum l
```

As the error message suggest you need to supply a list of numbers to `sum`. Here's the signature of `sum`:

```
λ> :t sum
sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
```

It takes a `Foldable` of `Num`s and returns a `Num`.